# Obtain client secret id from API AZURE AD

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a use case of obtain the access token owner of Azure AD.

I am generating the access token as follows:

```
class MsalAuthentication(ServiceProvider):
    """Authentication with msal"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cli = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
            client_id=Secrets.AZURE_API_CLIENT_ID.get_value(),
            authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Secrets.AZURE_API_TENANT_ID.get_value()}",
            client_credential=Secrets.AZURE_API_CLIENT_SECRET.get_value(),
        )

    def get_token(self):
        """Gets authentication token from microsoft"""
        self.logger.info("Getting token for msal authentication !")
        response = self.cli.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[
            Secrets.AZURE_API_CLIENT_ID.get_value() + "/.default"
        ])
    return response
```

When I perform an API request with this particular token, how do I identify the the client secret id(Which is on the `Certificates & secrets` section) from the receiving side?

Even though we can distinguish user with the `oid` I can't find the ID on the Azure portal.

Or how do I fetch non-human user information by `oid`?

Comment: you need to create an application in azure active directory and then go to the "Certificates & secrets" section and add the secrets. Note this secret will be shown once when you save. Now you will Application (client) ID & secret which you can use for getting token

Comment: @RahulShukla Yeah I have done all that. Actually my requirement is after getting the token, getting the user(In my case not a human) info by OID. I want the secret_id in a particular record under Certificates & secrets.

Comment: Hello @Janukasamaranyake, May i know why you are looking for secretID in the token, is there any specific use case ?

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I want to know the token issuer. Since it's not a human most make sense id is the secretID if I want to backtrack the token issuer.

Comment: secretID is the GUID for the Client_secret that you are using for the . authentication with client_credentials flow

Comment: let me check if there is any possibility of getting the required information from client secret flow

Comment: using client_credential the token issuer will be `iss:` and it will be `"https://sts.windows.net/tenant-id/"`.

Comment: and as you are using client credentials .. your oid will be the object id of the app i.e. service principal / enterprise application